# arrays indexados que no pueden ser ordenados

Tags: php, array

```
Array (
[searchResult] => Array
    (
        [search] => Array
            (
                [results] => Array
                    (
                        [nombre] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => victor
                                [1] => ivan
                            )
                        [cargo] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => programador
                                [1] => programador
                            )
                        [sueldo] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 1
                                [1] => 2
                            )
                    )
            )
    )
)
```

tengo un problema al momento de poder ordenar este array, ya que no consigo poder hacer que los index vayan juntos, es decir:

- [0] victor
- [0] programador
- [0] 1
- [1] ivan
- [1] programador
- [1] 2

sin embargo la respuesta que obtengo al  recorrer los arrays es la siguiente:

- [0] victor
- [0] ivan
- [1] programador
- [1] programador
- [2] 1
- [2] 2

Espero alguien pueda ayudarme con este problema, adjunto el código que estoy usando. De antemano gracias!!

```
foreach($food as $resultado => $nivel1) {
echo "<b> $resultado </b>";
echo "<hr>";
foreach($nivel1 as $indice => $indice1) {
    //echo "<p> $indice </p>";
    foreach($indice1 as $indice2 => $indice3) {
        //echo "<p> $indice2 </p>";
        foreach($indice3 as $indice4 => $indice5) {
            echo "<b><p> $indice4 </p></b>";
            echo "<br>";
            foreach($indice5 as $indice6 => $valor) {
                echo $indice6. " ". "$indice4 " . "" . $valor;
                echo "<br>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Disculpa, ¿la idea es agrupar los datos en base a los indices?. No lo tomes mal, pregunto porque en tu código no veo que intenes ordenar nada.

Comment: Me parece que estás confundiendo cosas. Un array asociativo no se ordena, las entradas no tinen un orden. Los arrays (no asociativos) que en tu ejemplo son nombre, cargo, y sueldo, son tres arrays separados pero relacionados entre sí por la posición de sus elementos. Si ordenas estos arrays se van a mezclar los datos relacionados.

Comment: Otra duda, ¿tienes acceso a modificar la forma en que generas ese arreglo o tienes que si o si trabajar con ese formato?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: @Marcos Así es amigo y no hay problema no lo tomo a mal incluso me gustaría saber en que estoy mal, no no tengo acceso a modificar ya que esto que hice yo es la representación de un response soap que me da respuesta any

Comment: @Juan entonces y para tratarlo como array no asociativo, como debería de ser la forma de recorrerlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error está en que iteras elemento por elemento en `results` cuando deberías iterar por indice partir de ahí

```
foreach($indice3 as $indice4 => $indice5) {
     /* Aquí $indice4 es "nombre, cargo y sueldo" e $indice 5 es el array asociado*/
     echo "<b><p> $indice4 </p></b>";
     echo "<br>";
          foreach($indice5 as $indice6 => $valor) {
               /*Aquí $indice6 es 0 ó 1, y $valor, el valor
               echo $indice6. " ". "$indice4 " . "" . $valor;
               echo "<br>";
          }
 }
```

Como puedes ver en el último foreach siempre itera sobre todos los elementos, por eso te salen seguido los elementos, debería quedar así

```
foreach($a as $resultado => $nivel1) {
    echo "<b> $resultado </b>";
    echo "<hr>";
    foreach($nivel1 as $indice => $indice1) {
        //echo "<p> $indice </p>";
        foreach($indice1 as $indice2 => $indice3) {
            //echo "<p> $indice2 </p>";
            for($i=0;$i < count(max($indice3)); $i++) { //iteras sobre el número de elementos máximo en results
                foreach($indice3 as $indice4 => $indice5) {
                    echo "<b><p> $indice4 </p></b>";
                    echo "<br>";
                    if(isset($indice5[$i])) { //si existe ese indice en cada uno de los elementos de result, lo imprime
                        echo $i. " ". "$indice4 " . "" . $indice5[$i];
                        echo "<br>";
                    }
                 }
             }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias @Sr1871, justamente eso es lo que buscaba.

Answer (score 1):

Por lo charlado en los comentarios, entiendo que la idea es agrupar los datos de las *"personas"* en base al indice.

### Solución:

Podemos crear un arreglo de *"personas"* en el cual vamos a ir guardando cada *"persona"* con sus *"atributos"*.

Al iterar el arreglo `results` vamos a obtener la lista de *"atributos"* de las *"personas"*.

Al iterar el arreglo de *"atributos"* vamos a obtener:

- El indice: que nos indica a que *"persona"* le corresponde
- El valor: que nos indica el valor del *"atributo"*

#### Ejemplo

```
$results = $response['searchResult']['search']['results'];
$personas = [];
foreach($results as $atributo => $valores) {
    foreach($valores as $indice => $valor) {
        // Si la persona no existe, la creamos
        if (!isset($personas[$indice])) $personas[$indice] = [];
        
        $personas[$indice][$atributo] = $valor;
    }
}
var_export($personas);
```

Salida:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'nombre' => 'victor',
    'cargo' => 'programador',
    'sueldo' => 1,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'nombre' => 'ivan',
    'cargo' => 'programador',
    'sueldo' => 2,
  ),
)
```

<kbd>[`Demo`](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e9e49587ab7855f2082842de6fc9e56a073ba290)</kbd>

Comment: Hola @Marcos muchísimas gracias, con tu respuesta puedo incluso convertir los datos a formato json, gracias!!

Comment: @VictorCarbajal si funciono recuerda dar un +1 a la respuesta